# Double Tap on Android ListView ListItem

Tags: android, user-interface

This is a question that I know has been asked many times before, but I'm having a very hard time finding a solution that works for me. I'm also not that great of a programmer.

I currently have a list view, and I like the way the single tap highlights the listitem before it fires onListItemClick. I also like the way that the long click bring up the context menu.

Is there anyway to retain this functionality while implementing a double click listener (double tap listener)?

Is there code I could just place in onListItemClick that could detect a double tap? If I don't mind a small delay?

Mike.

Comment: "Is there code I could just place in onListItemClick that could detect a double tap?" -- no, because by definition, the second tap will not have occurred yet. Also, note that a double-tap is not a common gesture in Android.